# How can I get only elements with odd ids from a D3 selection?

Tags: d3.js

How can I get only elements with odd indices using D3 selection?

```
var theData = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

var p = d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
  .data(theData)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .text("hello");
```

In this case (I know that this code does not make a lot of sense), I would like to get the elements with indices 1 and 3.

An example fiddle is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/8tvdbfxs/

Comment: What do you mean by *odd* IDs? Your code does not feature any ID at all! Did you mean to say *every other* element, i.e. every element at an odd position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [updated your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f7nrkyxL/1/) with an example solution. I added 
a selector to get all odd children from the body. D3 can use any [css selector](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection). This allows you to use pseudo-selectors like `:nth-child`. For my example I have just changed the color of the text.

```
d3.select("body").selectAll(':nth-child(odd)')
    .style('color', 'orange');
```

Comment: I wanted to only get the elements add odd positions and remove all others. Your solution goes in the right direction, however...

Comment: @FranzHuber23 Good. Your question didn't explicitly state what your desired outcome was so I just put the selector.

Comment: No problem, it was my fault. I did not make it clear enough I guess.